# Updating multiple Textboxes in parallel

Tags: vb.net

I want to update multiple textboxes' value in parallel. I read about `Parallel.invoke` can do this but I don't know how to implement it. This is the code

```
Private Sub UpdateWithInvoke(lst As List(Of String))
        'System
        TextBoxSystemName.Text = lst.Item(0)
        TextBoxSystemUptime.Text = lst.Item(1)
        TextBoxSystemDateTime.Text = lst.Item(2)
        TextBoxSystemFirmVersion.Text = lst.Item(3)
        TextBoxSystemBuildDate.Text = lst.Item(4)
        TextBoxSystemSerialNumber.Text = lst.Item(5)
        TextBoxSystemCpuUsage.Text = lst.Item(6)
        TextBoxSystemMemoryUsage.Text = lst.Item(7)
    End Sub
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have now? It will execute in a few microseconds, which I sincerely doubt is an issue for you. You cannot update UI controls from a background thread anyway so using `Parallel` makes no sense.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes, the code works fine. I'm just experimenting what will happen.

Comment: So what actually are you asking, if the code works fine?

Comment: What will happen is that it'll immediately throw an [**`InvalidOperationException`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception(v=vs.110).aspx) because the .NET Runtime doesn't allow you to access controls on the UI (User Interface) thread from a background thread. All UI related work must be synchronized.